# how to install fishhook.c react native library for ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

this error happens when I push my code to my GitHub, ​could you show me how to install fishhook.c library

I have tried to copy pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => ['DevSupport', 'fishhook'] and paste it into my podfile

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
>   '/Users/apple/Documents/Documents - Apple’s MacBook Pro/IOS
>   Project/react-native/AppTracking/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook/fishhook.c'
>
> error: Build input file cannot be found:
>   '/Users/apple/Documents/Documents - Apple’s MacBook Pro/IOS
>   Project/react-native/AppTracking/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook/fishhook.c'